# Getting 'Error cannot find parameter' when creating category with Magento SOAP API v1 and Savon Ruby Gem v2

Tags: ruby, api, magento, soap, savon

### Background

I'm trying to create a category through the Magento SOAP API using [Savon](http://savonrb.com/version2/). Before anyone suggests it, I can't use the Magento SOAP v2 or REST APIs.

This code sets up my client and logs in:

```
@client = Savon.client(wsdl: "#{EnvConfig.base_url}/api/soap/?wsdl", log_level: :debug, raise_errors: true, pretty_print_xml: true)

response = @client.call(:login, message: {
  username: EnvConfig.magento_api_user,
  apiKey: EnvConfig.magento_api_key
})

@token = response.to_hash[:login_response][:login_return]
```

I'm then able to call magentos various methods. To [list all of the products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html), I can call:

```
@response = @client.call(:call, message: {session: @token, method: 'catalog_product.list'})
```

This all works properly, so there doesn't seem to be a problem with any of the code above.

### The problem

When I call [catalog_category.create](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.create.html), I'm getting an error. If I call the method with only the parentID parameter:

```
  @response = @client.call(:call, message: {session: @token, method: 'catalog_category.create', parent_id: 90})
```

then the following XML is sent by Savon:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <typens:call>
      <session>6939ace91ba26b1da9a21334d7ef2c13</session>
      <method>catalog_category.create</method>
      <parentId>90</parentId>
    </typens:call>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

This returns the response `Savon::SOAPFault: (103) Attribute "name" is required`:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>103</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Attribute "name" is required.</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'd expect this, as [the API documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.create.html) makes it clear that the following attributes are not optional:

- parentId
- categoryData

  - name
  - is_active
  - available_sort_by
  - default_sort_by
  - include_in_menu

So If I make a call containing `name`:

```
@response = @client.call(:call, message: {session: @token, method: 'catalog_category.create', parent_id: 90, category_data: {name: 'Fooooo'}})
```

This XML is sent:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <typens:call>
      <session>6939ace91ba26b1da9a21334d7ef2c13</session>
      <method>catalog_category.create</method>
      <parentId>90</parentId>
      <categoryData>
        <name>Fooooo</name>
      </categoryData>
    </typens:call>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But I get a `Savon::SOAPFault: (SOAP-ENV:Client) Error cannot find parameter` error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Error cannot find parameter</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've spent quite a long time trying to work this out, and have tried sending the `name` parameter without wrapping it in categoryData, as well as other parameters. All return the same error message.

At the very least, it would be good to know *which* parameter can't be found!

Any help would really be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you still working on this? Have you tried to create a correct SOAP request with SoapUI?

Comment: Managed to 'solve' the problem by building the XML myself. I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could't really find a decent solution to this. In the end it was solved by building out the XML myself with this extremely messy code:

```
# Builds an XML Request for use with the Magento API
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Usage:
#
# @m = MageAPI.new(token, call, params)   Creates a new MageAPIRequest object with @call, @token, @data and
#                                           @xml_data instance variables.
#
# Expects a hash of params like:
#
#      { parentId: '90',
#        categoryData: {
#          name: 'OMG, does this work?',
#          is_active: 1,
#          available_sort_by: 'position',
#          default_sort_by: 'position',
#          description: 'Foo',
#          url_key: 'url_key',
#          include_in_menu: 1}
#      }
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MageAPIRequest
  attr_reader :call, :token, :data, :xml_data
  def initialize(token, call, params = {})
    @call = call
    @token = token
    @data = params
    @xml_data = build_xml
  end

  def to_s
    return @xml_data
  end

  # Build out the xml string to send to the server, excluding the Envelope, body and call tags, which are added by Savon.
  def build_xml
    token = LibXML::XML::Node.new('sessionId', @token)
    token['xsi:type']='xsd:string'
    resourcePath = LibXML::XML::Node.new('resourcePath', @call)
    resourcePath['xsi:type']='xsd:string'

    unless @data.empty?
      args = LibXML::XML::Node.new 'args'
      args['SOAP-ENC:arrayType'] = "xsd:ur-type[#{@data.length}]"
      args['xsi:type'] = 'SOAP-ENC:Array'

      # Build the structure insude 'args', based on the Hash.
      # TODO: Make this recursive, so it can work deeper than one level.
      @data.each do |k,v|
        if v.is_a? Hash

          details = LibXML::XML::Node.new(k.to_s)
          details["xsi:type"] = 'ns2:Map'
          args << details

          v.each do |key,value|

            item_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("item")

            key_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("key", key.to_s)
            key_node['xsi:type'] = 'xsd:string'

            if value.is_a? Fixnum
              value_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("value", value.to_s)
              value_node['xsi:type'] = 'xsd:int'
            elsif value.is_a? Float
              value_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("value", sprintf("%.2f", value))
              value_node['xsi:type'] = 'xsd:string'
            elsif value.is_a? Array
              value_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("value")
              value_node['SOAP-ENC:arrayType'] = "xsd:int[#{value.length}]"
              value_node['xsi:type'] = 'SOAP-ENC:Array'

              value.each do |v|
                v_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("item", v.to_s)
                v_node['xsi:type'] = 'xsd:string'
                v_node['xsi:type'] = 'xsd:int' if v.is_a? Fixnum
                value_node << v_node
              end

            else
              value_node = LibXML::XML::Node.new("value", value.to_s)
              value_node['xsi:type'] = 'xsd:string'
            end

            item_node << key_node
            item_node << value_node
            details << item_node

          end

        else
          pair = LibXML::XML::Node.new(k.to_s, v.to_s)
          # if v.is_a? Fixnum
          #    pair['xsi:type']='xsd:int'
          # else
            pair['xsi:type']='xsd:string'
          # end
          args << pair
        end
      end
    end
    xml_string = token.to_s
    xml_string << resourcePath.to_s
    xml_string << args.to_s
  end


end
```

I then used that when creating my request:

```
request = MageAPIRequest.new(@token, call, params)
```

Far from ideal, but it works. It's worth noting that I also had to build a parser to turn the responses which look like this:

```
  {:balance=>"10",
    :exchange_rate=>"1.000000",
    :response_type=>"ACCEPT",
    :customer_data=>
      {:item=>
        [
          {:key=>"iredeem_member_id", :value=>"110"},
          {:key=>"prefix", :value=>"Ms."},
          {:key=>"lastname", :value=>"Last name"},
          {:key=>"firstname", :value=>"First name"},
          {:key=>"iredeem_points_balance", :value=>"10"},
        ]
      }
  }
```

into something useable like this:

```
  {:balance=>"10",
    :exchange_rate=>"1.000000",
    :response_type=>"ACCEPT",
    :customer_data=>
      {:iredeem_member_id=>"110",
       :prefix=>"Ms.",
       :lastname=>"Last name",
       :firstname=>"First name",
       :iredeem_points_balance=>"10"
      }
  }
```

Comment: From the top of my head I'd say you can use Savon with builder and have it parse the result. But don't touch it if it works :-).

Comment: I seem to remember trying to use builder and finding that (surprisingly) it was less painful to use LibXML.